# Best country for humans with superpowers to hide?

Tags: politics, geography, super-powers

In the story I'm thinking to write there's a group of **50 000 humans with superpowers**. These powers cause them to have **great weaknesses** so they decide to 
hide.

### Which countries or regions of large countries would be the best?

These are their requirements:

- The place should be **safe**, and so: not involved in wars that may affect people living in it; severe contagious illnesses shouldn't be common; political and social breakdowns that may result in large amounts of deaths should happen rarely.
- The environment should be **liveable** and the weather not too extreme: it should be possible to survive isolated without large use of technology.
- There should be some kind of **resources** to allow these people to survive without depending much on others.
- If necessity arise, it should be possible to reach **services** like the hospital in less than a day or two.
- They don't want to have big problems, so they should be able to **hide** and live well **without** extensive use of **technology** or there should be **no reason why the government**, even knowing someone illegally hides in its country, **would care** about them or **the country or/and the government** should have a history that there are reasons to think they **wouldn't persecute and oppress them**.

Thanks in advance for any answer you'll want to write.

Comment: Why **would** they be **illigal** just **because** they have **powers**?  They could **become** honest **citizens** like anyone **else**.

Comment: With "illegal" I mean "without having asked permission". It has nothing to do with superpowers.

Comment: Is the **superpower** in question the ability to **overuse bold?** In that case, I **understand** why that human would **want to hide!** ;-)

Comment: Yes. Why must they be *undocumented*? Why not be able to immigrate in a legal way without revealing the superpower?

Comment: Well, wikipedia says *be bold in editing*…

Comment: It's because of the weaknesses they have due to thier powers, which make them look like a large group of handicaped people at best and easily recognizable as superpowered at worst.

Comment: And, I used so much bold to make the points of the question easier to recognize, so just looking fast (I hope) one would get faster the main points.

Comment: faster recognition - you failed, specially in last paragraph. Brasil your choose - mild climate, hot womens.

Comment: I think the only problem here is that you are too early in your planning and that it is hard for us to give you direction because one decision can eliminate so many possibilities.  We just don't have enough information.

Answer (score 4):

I think that you are in the beginning stages as it seems as if you still don't have anything solid.

My thoughts are that you first need to determine if anyone knows that they exist.  In X-Men, their existence is know and some can pass in everyday life without anyone knowing about them.  In Harry Potter, they aren't necessarily weak; however, they have been persecuted in the past which leads to their desire to hide their society from muggle knowledge.  So, to start off, do their powers give them the ability to establish a society completely hidden from the modern world or will they be dependent upon the modern world to survive.

Next, I think you will need to determine what happens if an individual if found out.  In X-Men, it's kinda like coming out of the closet...can't exactly shut the door while Harry Potter has a backup plan (that gets used a lot--possibly overused--would have been a real bummer if using a memory modification charm on someone who had a blocked memory already caused the earlier modification to be undone).

If you have gone with the X-Men route, you ideally want to pick a country that is more "chill" and not as opinionated.  In the U.S., you have a highly opinionated society that is ruled by a majority (within Constitutional limitations of course).  In Africa, you have very weak governments that might not pose much of an issue, but you also have a weak infrastructure and a high degree of taboos (and people are willing to kill over it in some cases).  Regardless, you might be better off within the developed world where some degree of law might offer some protections.  Your biggest threat will be members of your own society and more specifically, the few whose actions are in the minority that push the more extreme members of the general public to hate you even more.

If you chose the Harry Potter route, then you could pick anywhere really.  They are self-sufficient capable of hiding themselves from the world.  In this case, your biggest threats also come from within.  The threat of exposure is the greatest and it can be achieved by a single person  In a population of 50,000, this is extremely easy if you are not isolated and is an eventuality should you have no way to combat it.

Regardless of your path, I think you should also come up with a list of certain powers that might be helpful in the establishment of your society.  It's hard for us to give you adequate help as that will play a major role.  If mind/memory manipulation is possible, many doors open for you and if not, then they close.  Also, things like power nullification (useful against others with powers) would be extremely beneficial when used in law enforcement and maintaining secrecy when in the right hands (but a detriment in the wrong hands).  So overall, I think you need to make the determination I suggested above and then figure out some key powers that will be necessary for your civilization to be established.

Answer (score 3):

**United States**.

You just need to find a religion with the correct for your purposes religious dogma. Conveniently, instead of saying "because it helps hide our super-powers or super-weaknesses", you can just say "because the great spaghetti monster told me so in a dream". Works for anything.

Explaining why you all want to live in a single isolated community that does most of its own medical services and basic education and has no facilities for visiting non-believers shouldn't be a problem. And since freedom of religion is politically heavily protected you'd be in much stronger position relative to authorities than normal citizens are.

Additionally, many religions or group classified as such in the US claim that following their tenets can give supernatural or unusual abilities. Make such a claim and spread rumours of such abilities as well as proven cases of where you faked such abilities and any embarrassing mistakes will fade into the background. The CIA actually adopted such a strategy to handling leaks after the congress accidentally caught them blatantly ignoring the law, and it kind of works, probably, maybe. Impossible to know, which is kind of the whole idea.

Maybe a separate splinter group that claims to have split off to make the secret the main group hides available to all, but really just exists to create smoke without fire to convince everyone there is no fire at all even if they notice some smoke.

EDIT:
The reason the US is best is because elsewhere the religion actually has to make sense and the authorities will at least look (pretty casually, but still) what you are up to. In the US, religions are assumed to be above sense and reason, so you are fine as long as you don't commit actual crimes or cause problems to other people.

Comment: I'm not sure that "because the great spaghetti monster told me so in a dream"  _is_ a plausible response. I am by no means a worshipper of the flying spaghetti monster, but I'm certain that there will be an over-opionionated/crazed reporter/allout WHACKO (take your pick) that renders your religious coverup useless.

Answer (score 2):

You have a problem here. The countries with a decent infrastructure, modern medical services, etc. tend to be worried about illegal immigrants, and also about legal residents who "drop off the grid" to do their own thing and not pay taxes. The countries where the government does not care tend to be hellholes. So you need to find a place in between.

- The United States are out because of their terrorism concerns.
- The EU are out because of their welfare state. Child services might come looking for your people. Also, too densely populated.
- China and Russia are may be too totalitarian, unless the people are prepared to pay a huge bribe and find officials who will stay bought.
- Most of Africa and Central Asia/South-East Asia doesn't have the infrastructure you want.

That leaves South and Central America. Some places are stable enough the people might want to stay, yet poor enough to welcome some skilled immigrants. Compare [Chile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Villa_Baviera), [Bolivia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klaus_Barbie), [Panama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mossack_Fonseca).

Or Canada or Australia, if most of the people are willing to live in a normal city, work ordinary jobs, etc. They could buy large "weekend homes" in the outback.

But if you look for a place where "weird" people can live openly and undisturbed, look for the smaller Western countries. Scandinavia, Iceland, Holland, Denmark. The latter have taken a swing towards nationalism in recent years, but they are still a very liberal place.

Comment: Russia is ok, nobody cares, although 50k, if they wish live in dense group is too much. If thats not the case, no problem, there enough aliens, be good man thats all you need. Bribing is needed in business, if they wish just rural live I see no  problem.

Comment: New Zealand would be nice

Comment: @user23614, 50k people would be one percent of the NZ population. Too much to vanish into the background, too little to become a political force at the ballot box.